# Why does ajax return "Page not found" error when the number of my table columns are more than 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Whenever I fetch records using ajax function, I get the following error. This is mainly caused by increasing the number of dataTable columns beyond 8. When 8, below, it works perfectly well.

Server Error:

```
404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

It is basically a dataTable error. When I run this project in local Xampp, it runs perfectly well. But now I want to move to a Windows Server on LAN (Windows Server 2012 R2, IIS). When the aoColumns are less than 8, the code works perfectly well.

Comment: Seems an error in the Windows Server. A failed configuration related with the numbers base. The comunication could be on 8 base and not in 10 base. Did you tried from 10 to 18?

Comment: We don't know your ajax call , we dont know your endpoint logic, we dont know how / if data is received and returned. Without any information at all, just a very generic error it's impossible to help you.

Comment: Dear Lapskaus, I am sorry. Here is the ajax call. <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#table').DataTable( {
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "<?php echo site_url('admin/data/get_data/user_list'); ?>",
            "aoColumn": [{"bSortable": false},{"bSortable":false},{"bSortable": false},{"bSortable":false},null,null,null,null,null,null,null]
        });}); So when ever I increase the number of columns to beyond, 8 I get the error.
</script>